# Add Text To Span After Image Error

Tags: javascript, html

Note: I am very new to Javascript.

Here is my attempt at achieving this:

```
$("#img").onerror = function(evt) {
    $(".card-error").next("#img-error").html("Error with image url");
});
```

This did not work.

When an "onerror" occurs - how do I add a text error message inside my "img-error" span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that instead:

```
$('#img').error(function () {
  $(".card-error").html("Error with image url");
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked - I needed to specifically use the img-error id so your code worked by just replacing .card-error with #img-error. I guess from now on I will avoid using .next with JS an just use error instead of onerror. Thanks a lot! It was a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [jQuery event handler method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#img').on("error", function() {
    $("#img-error").text("Error with image url");
});
```

You were assigning a property "onerror" to the  jQuery wrapper object, where it does nothing than getting garbage-collected. Assigning to the DOM element would've worked, such as

```
$("#img").get(0).onerror = … // or with plain DOM:
document.getElementById("img").onerror = …
```

Comment: The person's code below worked. For some reason, there is a problem with using .next - I don't know why - but it works without it

Comment: @JoseBazBaz: If you had selected the `span` by class name, `next()` will get the *next element sibling* (and only if it had the id "img-error"). You should just use the id only and omit the class.